# rewrite refuses to work

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache-2.4, ubuntu-14.04, http-status-code-404

I want to rewrite this url:

http://cyanogenupdatetracker.com/api/v1/show_devices.php

to http://cyanogenupdatetracker.com/api/v1/devices

I used this .htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^devices$ devices/
RewriteRule ^devices/$ /var/www/api/v1/show_devices.php
```

It always returns a 404 error, even though i know and am 100% sure that the php file exists at the given location.
I tried everything (no path before php file, custom vhosts, rewritebase) but none of this is working.

The apache config for this dir is as following:

```
Alias /api /var/www/api
    <Directory /var/www/api>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
```

I am completely done with this. It seems so simple (only a few php files) and why has it to be that hard, just to simplify the urls to make them nicer.

What am I doing wrong?????

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that within the context of a `.htaccess` file [Pass Through](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_pt) is implied.

Effectively that means that your RewriteRule doesn't map to a file-system location but to an URI path. That is needed, among others, to work well with Alias directives. Also check [this comparison](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html#rewrite).

`cyanogenupdatetracker.com/api/v1/devices` probably ended being redirected to something like `cyanogenupdatetracker.com/api/v1/var/www/api/v1/show_devices.php`. Your rule should have looked like:

```
RewriteRule ^devices/$ show_devices.php
```

Second, my pet peeve, why are you using an `.htaccess` file in the first place when you obviously have access to the main apache configuration file? Quoted from from the [manual on .htaccess](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html#when) files:

> You should **avoid using `.htaccess` files completely** *if you have access to httpd main server config* file. Using **`.htaccess` files slows down your Apache http server**. Any directive that you can include in a `.htaccess` file is better set in the main Apache configuration file(s), as it will have the same effect with better performance.
>   ...
>   Likewise, mod_rewrite directives work better, in many respects, in the main server configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed myself by changing documentroot from /var/www/html to /var/www as the api folder was outside of /var/www/html.